# UITabBarController with UINavigationController, hide UINavigationController toolbar on hidesBottomBarWhenPushed, not UITabBarController tab bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` root view controller with three view controllers, once of which is a `UINavigationController` with a `UIViewController` containing a `UISearchDisplayController` and a `UITableView`.  The `UINavigationController` toolbar is not hidden.

However, when I select a row in the `UITableView`, I would like to push another `UIViewController`.  When this `UIViewController` is pushed, the `UINavigationController` toolbar should slide out and the `UITabBarController` tab bar should remain visible.

I tried setting the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property of the pushed `UIViewController` to true (which provides the intended behavior when the `UINavigationController` is not nested within a `UITabBarController`).  Unfortunately, rather that sliding the `UINavigationController` toolbar out when hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is set to true, the `UITabBarController` slides out, leaving the `UINavigationController` visible in the pushed `UIViewController` as the bottom bar.

How might slide out the `UINavigationController` toolbar when pushed, and not the `UITabBarController` tab bar?

**EDIT #1**:
The only possible solution I can think of is, rather than using the `UINavigationController` toolbar, simply add a `UIToolbar` to the bottom of the `UIViewController` view containing the `UITableView`.  This will assure that the `UIToolbar` slides out when the new `UIViewController` is pushed and slides in when the new `UIViewController` is popped.  The only problem is, for the iPhone and iPod Touch, unlike the `UINavigationController` toolbar, the height of a `UIToolbar` instance (44 pixels) will not shrink to 30+ pixels in height (like the `UINavigationController` toolbar does) when the device is rotated in to a landscape orientation.  If this is the only legitimate solution, how might I change the height of a `UIToolbar` to match the height of the `UINavigationController` toolbar in landscape?

**EDIT #2**:
Regarding EDIT #1, I suppose the frame of the `UIToolbar` could be changed in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.  I would still like to find a solution for sliding out the `UINavigationController` toolbar, though.  Better than creating a separate `UIToolbar` for every `UIViewController` I wish have a bottom toolbar.

**EDIT #3**:
Basically, here is what I have (this is the result of hidesBottomBarWhenPushed): http://flic.kr/p/bcjydn

And, here is what I would like to achieve: http://flic.kr/p/bcjybK

**EDIT #4**:
Firstly, thank you for your time.  Secondly, unfortunately, the setToolbarHidden:animated: method in UINavigationController is unable to produce the slide out/slide in animations as seen with setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed: (refer to the links in **EDIT #3**, specifically the second link, for the desired animation).  For example, assume we write:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

in the parent view controller (the view controller in which the toolbar is not hidden), and assume we write:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

in the child view controller (the view controller in which the toolbar is hidden).

As soon as we push the child view controller on to the UINavigationController stack from the parent view controller, the child view controller viewWillAppear: method will be called.  This will simply hide the UINavigationController toolbar (before the push animation starts), exposing the portion of the UIWindow that lies beneath the UINavigationController toolbar.  The remainder of the push animation executes as expected (UINavigationController toolbar still not visible in the child view controller, everything resized appropriately).  Then, when we pop the child view controller, the viewWillAppear: method will be called for the parentViewController, which will unhide the UINavigationController toolbar (making the toolbar visible in the child view controller), then the pop animation will execute.  The remainder of the pop animation executes as expected (UINavigationController toolbar still visible in the parent view controller, everything resized appropriately).

Kind of figured this question was going to lead down a rathole.  The only remaining ideas I have are:

1)  **EDIT #1** (though that implementation is limited by the inability to appropriately or legally alter the height of a standard UIToolbar instance an iPod Touch or iPhone is in landscape; one reason why I am hellbent on using the UINavigationController's toolbar).

2)  Either subclass UITabBar or UITabBarController to try to prevent the setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed: method from realizing that the UITabBarController tab bar is the bottom bar.  Basically, bypass the tab bar and pass the UINavigationController toolbar instead.  Probably the most promising idea, but potentially the most difficult (as the knowledge of the setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed: innards is limited, and since private APIs might be required).

Comment: what you want to hide or what you show in next screen? if possible show code

Comment: I added EDIT #3 to my post.  This will give you an idea of what I have right now (using setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to YES for the UIViewController I am drilling down to).  And, it will give you an idea of what I would like to achieve.  I am beginning to think that EDIT #1 may be the easiest solution.  But, it is also the bulkiest solution.  Not to mention, to resize the height of a UIToolbar instance (like the UINavigationController toolbar), you need to set the autoResizingMask or the frame for the toolbar, both of which don't seem to be suggested by the HIG.

Answer (score 3):

when you push your navigation bar controller 
write the code like

```
YourController = [[YourController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourController" bundle:nil]
controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = TRUE;
[self.navigatoinController pushViewController:controller Animated:YES];

//// Try this code where you want to hide navigation bar

-(void)viewWillAppear{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you hiren443.  Exactly.  This is what I have.  And, by definition, I suppose it works.  It hides the bottom bar (in this case, the UITabBarController tab bar).  Unfortunately, I do not want to hide the tab bar, I want to hide the UINavigationController toolbar (the second bar from the bottom).  This code, as is, results in the first image in EDIT #3.  I would like to achieve the second image in EDIT #3.

Comment: Hi hiren443.  You provided a similar solution to VinceBurn, so I responded with **EDIT #4** above.

Comment: so did you took the toolbar in the bottom bar above tabbar? you want to hide this toolbar?

Comment: fyi, in story boards, there's an option for the view that will be pushed

Comment: @vinnybad Thanx, I have not knowledge of storyboard pattern

Comment: ah ok.  storyboards were introduced in ios5 and gets rid of a lot of the view code that you would sometimes have to write yourself.  there are many more things it introduces but thats a 1-sentence intro to it :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIViewController`'s method `viewWillAppear` make the following call

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

That bar belong the the UINavigationController. While I've never used `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` it look like it's going for the most bottom bar it can find.

Comment: Thank you, VinceBurn.  I forgot to mention, I did try this as well.  Obviously, this allows you to hide and unhide the UINavigationController toolbar.  That's good.  The only problem: When hiding, instead of sliding out with the UIViewController with the UITableView, it remains visible until the pushed UIViewController is visible, then is slides down.  Slides up, instead of sliding instead, when popping back.

Comment: @NicholasPeters pass it `animated:NO` and you will have what you want

Comment: Hi VinceBurn.  You provided a similar solution to hiren443, so I responded with **EDIT #4** above.